# How to map forward port on azure container instance using a YAML file

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, yaml, azure-container-instances

The Azure Container Instances YAML reference gives option to expose multiple ports in the container.
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml

However, I haven't figured out yet how to map/forward port as we do with docker. I would like to define on the YAML file a port forward, as we do with docker command:

```bash
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=pw' -p 14000:1433
```

Is there a limitation using Azure YAML schema?

I have tried:

```
      ports:
      - port: 11401
      - port: 1433
```

but it opens both ports.

Answer (score 1):

As per the below document, Azure Container Instances **not supporting** port mapping like in Docker.

Please **refer** this doc for more details: [Troubleshoot common issues - Azure Container Instances | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting)

The port which you expose in container instance should be **same** as port your container image listens to.

However, you can achieve it by defining arguments and environment variables in the docker file which lets you overwrite port during deployment.

For example, by default, the below docker file will listens to http port 80 as `http_port` is set to 80.

```
#Dockerfile
FROM TestImage
ARG http_port=80
ENV target_port ${http_port}
.
.
.
```

But if you require ACI to listen on different port then define target_port in the environment variables of ACI deployment yaml file as shown below.

```
#Azure container instance yaml file

apiVersion: ‘2021-10-01’
location: <location-name>
name: <container instance group name>
properties:
     containers:
       - name: <container-name>
         properties:
            image: <image-name:version>
            environmentVariables:
              - name: target_port
                value: 8090 # once this environment variable defined, the port in the image will change to 8090.
          ports:
             - port: 8090
               protocol: tcp
      ipAddress:
          type: Public  #value can be Public or Private
          ports:
            - protocol: tcp
              port: 8090
      type: Public
type:Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Once the above has file has deployed, Azure Container Instance starts listen to port 8090 even image port is 80.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/sidecar-containers.md#networking-for-host-jobs) and [doc](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/), please try with format :

```
   ports:
      - "14000:1433"
```